# What language is this? (for an IRC Bot)

Tags: irc, bots

Finally found some of my really old scripts I had written for an IRC Bot about 10 years ago. I had no idea what I was doing, and was wondering if anyone knew what this was written in and any information?

```
on *:sockread:$1:{
  var %stattype $1
  if ($sockerr) {
    .notice [ %nickname [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] Error.
    halt
  }
  else {
    var %statread
    sockread %statread
    if (Stat:* * * * iswm %statread) {
      .tokenize 32 %statread
      .notice [ %nickname [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] 1[ Username:7 $upper( [ %username [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] ) 1] [ Skill: 7 $upper(%stattype) 1] 
      .notice [ %nickname [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] 1[ Level:7 $3 1 $chr(124) Exp:7 $4 1 $chr(124) Rank:7 $2 1]
      .notice [ %nickname [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] 1[ Next lvl:7 $calc($3 + 1) 1 $chr(124) Exp to:7 $bytes($calc( [ %lvl [ $+ [ $calc($3 + 1) ] ] ] - $remove($4,$chr(44))),b) 1]
      .notice [ %nickname [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] 1[ Bandits:7 $bytes($calc($calc( [ %lvl [ $+ [ $calc($3 + 1) ] ] ] - $remove($4,$chr(44)))/(51*1.33)),b) 1 $chr(124) S.Warriors:7 $bytes($calc($calc( [ %lvl [ $+ [ $calc($3 + 1) ] ] ] - $remove($4,$chr(44)))/(67*1.33)),b) 1 $chr(124) Dagg(74):7 $bytes($calc($calc( [ %lvl [ $+ [ $calc($3 + 1) ] ] ] - $remove($4,$chr(44)))/(70*1.33)),b) 1 $chr(124) Ogre(53)/Ice Warrior:7 $bytes($calc($calc( [ %lvl [ $+ [ $calc($3 + 1) ] ] ] - $remove($4,$chr(44)))/(60*1.33)),b) 1]
      .sockclose %stattype
    }
  }
}

on $*:TEXT:$(/@(hp|att|str|ran|mag|pra|def|coo|woo|fir|fle|run|sla|min|smi|cra)/):#: {
  var %stattype $left($remove($1,!,@),3)
  .tokenize %stattype 32
  if ($2 != $null) {
    sockopen %stattype rscript.org 80
    set [ %username [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] $2
    set [ %nickname [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] $nick
  }
  elseif ($2 == $null) {
    sockopen hp rscript.org 80
    set [ %username [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] $nick
    set [ %nickname [ $+ [ %stattype ] ] ] $nick
  }
  else {
    .notice $nick Error. Sorry.
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably a custom scripting language for a particular IRC client.

Comment: This question proves the importance of code comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [mIRC scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIRC_scripting_language) for the mIRC client.

---

Oh and it seems to do something with (pff knowledge from when I was 12) training thieving on bandits in the game runescape through the service [rscript.org](http://rscript.org/).

Comment: Yup it was definitely a stat retriever for RS. Thanks for the mIRC tip.

Answer (score 3):

[MIRC Remote Events](http://dooyoo-uk.tripod.com/mirc/events.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you wrote your program in the mIRC scripting language (inofficial mSL). You can find more about that on its official [website](http://www.mirc.com/links.html). Currently i try to figure out what are you doing ;) I stay tuned.

Comment: Oh I know what I was doing, it was part of a larger block of code to look up someone Runescape stats on certain chat events. Thanks for the help